# does this look like an up to code support beam?

Tags: code-compliance, construction, support

we had an entry way widened a bit which required them to install a longer support beam. I'm absolutely not a professional. But the 2x4's supporting the larger beam don't seem very substantial to me. There's just one under each end of the cross beam.

Does anyone who is more knowledgeable about building practices/codes know if this is up to snuff? The width is about 8.5 feet
[image: support beam over 8.5 foot opening]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For an 8.5' span I'd say no.  The purpose of the jack studs isn't just to hold up the header - it also helps distribute the load more evenly to the foundation.  For that wide of a span the IRC calls for 2 jacks(see [R502.5 Allowable girder spans](http://publicecodes.cyberregs.com/icod/irc/2012/icod_irc_2012_5_par019.htm)).

Comment: Fortunately, it's very easy to put another jack stud or two on either side. Cut them a tiny bit long (1/16 to 1/8 inch) so you have to tap them into place with a hammer. They won't do any good if they're 1/16 short of touching that beam. If it takes a sledge hammer to put them in place, you cut them a little too long. ;-)

Comment: hmm, ok. Now i am wondering if they did that just to cut corners, or to try and make us happy since we wanted the walls to be flush but they couldn't do that without doing a lot of extra work. So i wonder if they did this to minimize how much of a lip there would be. Although in the picture i posted, i don't see why they couldn't have extended the beam another 3-4 inches into that wall and put the jack studs in the wall - unless that violates some building code.

Comment: Also, i'm not sure how to read that table. I think i'm supposed to be looking at the bottom table, interior bearing walls. It's only a single floor. Is building width the width of the whole building or just the section of wall we're dealing with? Is the size column the size and number of supporting jacks? If so what do the numbers in the span and NJ column mean?  Thanks

Comment: @merk - The size column is the number and size of the members.  For example, 2-2 x 12 would be 2 laminated 2x12s (which is what I'm seeing in the picture).  Span is feet - inches, and NJ is the number of jacks.  As for the table, it depends on what the header is supporting.  When you say it's only one floor, do you mean that the header is only supporting a roof load, or there's another floor above the header that it's supporting?

Comment: Apologies for not being clear - there's just a roof above. The whole house is just one floor.  The new beam they installed is a single 4x9

Comment: @merk - That would be nominally paired 2x10s.  *If* the only load is roof and ceiling load, most jurisdictions would use the top table for exterior walls.

Comment: Make sure the load of the beam/jack studs are transferred to the foundation. It may not be critical, since it is only an attic and roof above. It is common practice to have the load transferred through.

Comment: Hmm, so going by the exterior wall, it looks like there should be two studs supporting the beam. I assume the two supporting studs need to be directly under the beam? They did install 2 - although one of them is along side the beam and is attached to the beam with screws, and nailed together with the 2nd stud that is directly under the beam.

As long as this is reasonably safe I'm not going to say anything since i think they did this because we wanted there to be no lip, and they did this to minimize the protruding lip.

Comment: @merk - It does require 2, but the jack studs are the ones that go underneath the header.  The one on the left in your picture is called a king stud, and doesn't count toward the jack requirement.

Comment: Ah ok - thanks again for the info. The contractor is supposed to be pulling permits for all of this, although they've already started covering up the work with sheetrock, so i don't know how that's going to work as far as them being able to inspect the work.